# Cannot convert lambda expressions to type 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a custom helper defined in ASP.Net MVC 4 project as below

```
public static class CustomHelpers
{
    public static string UserNameForID(int UserIDValue)
    {
        // do database operation and return record for UserIDValue
        return "ABC";
    }
}
```

In my View I have the code

```
@model ABC.DataAccess.Product
@CustomHelpers.UserNameForID((model=>model.LAST_UPDATE_BY))
```

the above code gives this error:

> "Cannot convert lambda expressions to type 'int' becasue it is not a delegate type.

[image]

However if I test the above code a

```
@CustomHelpers.UserNameForID(1)
```

the application returns the string `ABC` as expected .

How to resolve this error? I would like to pass the value stored in `LAST_UPDATE_BY` of the model.

Comment: Why do you use double parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model=>model.LAST_UPDATE_BY` generates an argument from type `Expression<...>`. (For a sample see `Html.EditorFor()`.

your CustomHelpers Method wants an argument of type int, so you have to call it like:

```
@CustomHelpers.UserNameForID(Model.LAST_UPDATE_BY)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to cast an *expression* to the *result* of that expression.  Just use:

```
@model ABC.DataAccess.Product
@CustomHelpers.UserNameForID(Model.LAST_UPDATE_BY)
```